# Planting an Iframe as Aura component to show an external system that receives information from Salesforce API using oAuth web server flow

Tags: authentication, iframe, oauth, salesforce

I have built a web app for our sales team.
The web app is currently using oAuth web server flow in order to authenticate with Salesforce.

Everything is working fine when running it on a separate tab.

We recently wanted to add some functionality from within Salesforce specific objects and display information from our web app.

So I've built an aura component displaying an Iframe with the URL from our web app.

Unfortunately, it crashes with a console error

```
Refused to frame 'https://***.my.salesforce.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".
```

So I went to Salesforce's login page and indeed, there is a policy header that prevents it from being loaded from within an Iframe.

What is the correct way to authenticate the user with Salesforce in this situation?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a web app inside of an Iframe(Aura component) it would require the Salesforce domain calling it to be whitelisted in the web app.

Comment: Of course it is, that's not the problem. you can read my question again please.
The problem is Salesforce's login page security policy.

Comment: Ahh got it, did you try logging in with your salesforce domain?

Comment: Yes, I did.
I think I might need to authenticate using a different oAuth method (not webserver).
Do you know other methods and the difference between them?
Thanks

Comment: There are a few methods for Salesforce(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm)

This isn't working post CSP whitelisting?

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Unfortunately no, After whitelisting it still isn't working.
Tried to authenticate using both Webserver flow (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US) 
and User agent flow (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5&language=en_US).

Both of them are terminated with the same error in the same page (login page).